# Merge/concatenate all text files in a folder/directory older than 1 day into one text file in batch file (run.bat)

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I would like to merge text files that are older than 1 day into output.txt file in bat/cmd.

if I am running "run.bat" on 28th October 2021 for currently available files in folder where it should merge only 27th October 2021 dates files. so with below files in folder the "run.bat" should merge first three files

| File Name |
| --- |
| XXXXX_27Oct2021-050034.txt |
| YYYYY_27Oct2021-045233.txt |
| YYYYZ_27Oct2021-045233.txt |
| XXXXX_28Oct2021-050034.txt |
| YYYYY_28Oct2021-045233.txt |
| YYYYZ_28Oct2021-045233.txt |

presently I managed to merge with below cmd but it does merge all the text files into output.txt in folder.

`type *.txt > newfile.txt`

is there any way we can specify part of file name to search like this and merge

`set getDate = format(currentdate - 1,"ddMMMyyyy")`

`type %getDate% *.txt > newfile.txt`

apologies for wrong syntax or my thought process.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Could the solution involve third-party command-line tools?

Comment: thank you for response. no third-party command-line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little call out to Powershell within a batch file to get yesterday's date into a variable.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`powershell -command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('ddMMMyyyy')"`) do set "ydate=%%G"
```

Then you can use wildcards with the copy command to combine the files together.

```
copy "*_%ydate%-*.txt" "newfile.txt"
```

So this will only copy files with yesterdays date.  If you want all files older than 1 day then you would use the `FORFILES` solution.

Comment: Wow! it make sense the logic and it worked for me when I run manually but I am getting error as "The system cannot find the path specified." when I schedule through Task scheduler. any idea?

Comment: I got it worked by used Network folder path as it instead of mapped network path (net use).Thank you!! you are my life savior:)

Answer (score 2):

Using type and an output file is indeed an easy way to merge several txt files.
You can combine the type command with the ForFiles command in order to only type the files that are older than one day. This would look something like this:

```
ForFiles /p "C:\someFolder" /m *.txt /d -1 /c "cmd /c type @file" > output.txt
```

Comment: [Official Microsoft forfiles documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles).

Comment: trying but getting "ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@file '."

Comment: Seems like I made a mistake in the syntax. I edited the post should be fixed now.